# Splitting a Sequence with / in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I have a sequence that looks like this:

```
my $seq = "D\IKLR\LK/Q";
```

what I want to do is to break the sequence into individual letter.

So I hope to get:

```
my $var = ['D', '\', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'R', '\', 'L', 'K','/' ,'Q'];
```

But why this does'nt do it:

```
 my @chars = split(//,$seq);
 print Dumper \@chars;
```

It gave this instead:

```
my $var = ['D', '\\', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'R', '\\', 'L', 'K', 'Q'];
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: If you use double quotes in the assignment of `$seq` perl will think `\I` and `\L` are escapes and treat them as single characters. Since you that didn't happen, I assume this data comes from a filehandle. Also, is it a typo that you excluded `/` from your data dump?

Comment: If you write `my $seq = "D\IKLR\LK/Q";` then `$seq` will *not* contain a backslash character.  Backslashes within double-quoted strings are interpreted.  There's no defined meaning for `"\I"`, but it seems to be reduced to just the letter `"I"`.  The string you show for `$seq` has a backslash and a forward slash, but your `@chars` array has two backslashes.  I don't think you're showing us your actual code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are getting is exactly what you want.

The way to represent a single `\` is `'\\'` and not `'\'` as you expected because the `\` in `'\'` escapes the second `'` making the string incomplete but the `Data::Dumper` return value can always be `eval`ed as it's Perl code.

But printing the individual elements of the array by say looping over it will print `\`.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that `Data::Dumper` prints data structures as Perl code that can be `eval`ed to deserialize the structure. If you were to print the values in `@chars` directly, you would see the single `\\`'s that you expect. (Heheh - I had to type `\\\\` to get that to show up. And I had to type `\\\\\\\\` to get *that* to show up...)

Comment: friedo, use double backticks to escape, way easier than leaning toothpicks, see [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code). This is analogue to multiple angles as POD delimiters: `C<< method->call >>`.

Comment: you really should also mention that the OP could simply use single Quotes